# tar exclude not working

Tags: linux, bash

What's wrong with this tar command?

```
$ tar --exclude='/tmp/test/exclude-me' -zcvf test.tar.gz test
  test/
  test/c.txt
  test/exclude-me/
  test/exclude-me/b.txt
  test/a.txt
```

As you can see, `exclude-me` is present when I untar the archive. I also tried `--exclude=/tmp/test/exclude-me/*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `exclude` family of parameters apply to the **internal relative** names of the files in the tarball. The absolute path you specify will never exist within the tarball since it only has relative paths from the provided root.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but I still have a tricky exclude situation: I have the archive rooted at `a`, and I want to exclude `a/b`, but I want to keep `a/a/b`. Is that possible?

Comment: For more complex scenarios you can always first run `find` to an 'exclusion file' and then include that with `--exclude-from`. Full list of options [to be found here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html#SEC109).

Comment: Exclude patterns must match from the beginning of the filename unless the `--no-achored` option is used I believe.

Comment: @EtanReisner When I use `--exclude=dirname`, any directory with dirname is excluded, regardless of how deep it is in the file hierarchy.

Comment: @RosePerrone Then perhaps your default is inverted? Does using `--anchored` on the command change that behaviour?

Comment: @EtanReisner no. `--no-anchor` and `--anchor` both exclude all directories with `dirname`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to omit the absolute parts of the path.

In your example you use the v-flag and the included files are listed.

The exclude pattern is matched against the entries of this list, not to the actual file paths. So you have to change your pattern to "test/exclude-me".

For some reason you also have to remove the trailing / for folders.